# How to connect two cylinders to form a knee in Comsol Multiphysics?

Tags: comsol

I have this

[image]

I want it to be single bended wire.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

As an answer, in case of simple cylinders, it is enough to place a sphere with the radius of the cylinder at intersection of the cylinder axis.